# Scene View Axis of Movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a custom editor and in the scene view I want to be able to execute some code when the UP axis of movement is NOT selected. Is there a way to determine which control is selected before digesting the event in my OnSceneGUI()?

```
void OnSceneGUI() {
   if(/*UP AXIS*/) { 
      return; // use unity default action
   }
   // UP Axis not selected do stuff
   if (Event.current.isMouse 
       && Event.current.button == 0 
       && Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDrag) 
   {
      // do some stuff
      Event.current.Use(); // digest the event so unity doesn't do default
   }
}
```

[image: Axis I need to detect]

Comment: I think you can freeze y(up) axis and don't check anything more.Next for x and z movement you can check their position. for instance if x is increasing you can understand you are going to right .